# efforts by organizations vs organizations' efforts

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between *efforts by organizations* and *organizations' efforts* ?

Answer (score 1):

The former indicates passive voice whereas the latter is a genitive in active voice. For the first you ask *by whom*, the second you ask *whose efforts*? But they both indicate possession. 
A simple example could be:

> "It was owned by Peter"

and

> "Peter owned it".

Answer (score 0):

efforts by organizations to promote healthy eating vs
organizations' efforts to promote healthy eating
I know that there is a difference in meaning between these titles

Comment: In both examples the subject is 'efforts', which are the organization's. They both mean the same thing but are indicated differently, with the thrust of a passive vs. active voice marking that difference. Read my answer above.